What causes this strange killing behavior?
Sometimes during editing, the behavior of Emacs suddenly starts to change in that, when a selection is killed, the mark is not automatically turned off afterwards. Because I have delete-selection-mode on, his becomes extremely annoying, and I have no idea what causes it. I've turned off all my minor modes but the behavior remained the same: whenever some region was killed, the mark was not turned off afterwards. I have no idea what's causing this, and usually it appears when I'm deeply in the flow of editing, so I don't notice when it happens. What could be causing this, or how can I find out what's causing it?

Maybe start watching deactivate-mark when you notice the behavior. Once the behavior starts, does it continue consistently? Maybe you have something in your post-command-hook that causes this? All wild guesses at this point...

Do you see it with emacs -Q (no init file), and just turning on delete-selection-mode? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

@NickD Yes, across buffers and frames from what I can tell. and I haven't found a way to stop it, so I ended up restarting Emacs each time. post-command-hook could be it.

You might also want to show a step-by-step recipe, saying, at each step, what you do, what you see as effects, and what you expected to see instead.

@Drew The problem is, it doesn't happen immediately, but only after something happens and I haven't found out what triggers it. But next time it happens I'll try remember the last few things I did and add a step-by-step description.

“I'll try remember the last few things I did” You don't need to remember: press C-h l (view-lossage) to see your recent input.
